# Django Elastic Beanstalk Secret Variables

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to secure my secret variables for my django project, which is deployed on `AWS Elastic Beanstalk`.

I've seen others use `environment variables` and am wondering if this is secure. Or, is it more secure to use `KMS`? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually if you have secrets you would store them in [AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) or [AWS Secrets Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/intro.html).

Then, instead of hard-coding the secrets' values in your `.ebextensions` or `environment variables` you would **pass references** to the parameter or secret in either `AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store` or `AWS Secrets Manager`.

This means that in your application, e.g.  `.ebextensions`, in  you would need to add extra logic to **obtained the actual values** from the secrets as well as you would have to modify **instance role** used by EB with permissions to do so.

Comment: Will give this a shot. Thanks! What is KMS for then?